# Call Azure HTTP Trigger function from Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-functions, databricks, azure-databricks

I was trying to call a HTTP trigger azure function from my Databricks notebook. My function app is on an isolated plan (and I've turned on VNET peering from Databricks to Function App's vnet).
But I read in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/591652/call-azure-function-from-azure-databricks-notebook) that invocation of Azure function from Databricks is not possible. Has anyone done this recently?
TIA

I am trying to call my HTTP Trigger function to perform a certain action from my Databricks. This function does a common utility that I dont want to duplicate from Databricks

Comment: The answer in the thread you link is to use ADF Azure Data Factory,  that you can use as scheduler on top of az func and you databricks notebook

Answer (score 0):

> Call Azure HTTP Trigger function from Databricks

You can call Http Trigger from Databricks using below code and  I have created an Isolated Azure Function:

```
import requests
u = "https://rithfunc.azurewebsites.net/api/Function1?code=fBAbF_AzFur-kprw=="
requests.post(u)
```

[image]

Here u is the URL of the Azure Function.

**Output:**

[image]